# Product category Description Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code here for shortcodes

```php
function showtax_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'tax' => '',
    ), $atts );
    
    $termname = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),$a['tax'])[0]->name;
    return $termname;

}
add_shortcode( 'show_tax', 'showtax_func' );
```

How can I pass product_cat->ID or slug from woocommerce as a parameter?

This piece of code works to get all descriptions in single.php template,

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

$count = count($terms); 
if ($count > 0) {
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
      echo $term->description;
    }
}
```

I would like to add a single product category description to the single post as needed from shortcode within the post.

example: [product_cat="500"] or by slug... and I would get a description of the product category id 500 in the post.

Comment: Are you asking how your shortcode can return the WC Category Name by ID?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question as it's not understandable actually.

Comment: @HowardE I am asking how to get a description of the Product Category in the single Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I fully understand your question...

To make a shortcode to show product cat by ID, you need the shortcode name `product_cat` and the variable `id`

Then you can do this.

```php
function showtax_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts );
    
    // Get the term object by ID passed from shortcode
    $term = get_term_by('id', $a['id'], 'product_cat');
    
    return $term->description; // or anything from the WP_Term object.

}
add_shortcode( 'product-cat', 'showtax_func' );
```

useage is `[product-cat id="123"]`  - This returns the category description

Comment: is it possible to call this shortcode within a template? example: <?PHP do_shortcode('product-cat id="$var"');?>